# Bluetooth video streaming

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, video-streaming

I want to develop a mobile application to view the streaming video on using a bluetooth connection between a PC and a mobile phone.

On server side video will be captured from a web cam connected to it and this video should be viewed on the mobile phone in the form of streaming video.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Althouth your question is rather unspecific, here are a few things:

- [Java Bluetooth how-to](http://www.caside.lancs.ac.uk/java_bt.php)
- [JSR82 articles](http://www.jsr82.com/)
- [BlueCove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) - a JSR-82 J2SE implementation that currently interfaces with the Mac OS X, WIDCOMM, BlueSoleil and Microsoft Bluetooth stack
- [BlueZ](http://jbluez.sourceforge.net/) - Java package which interfaces with the BlueZ Bluetooth protocol stack for Linux, providing a simple means in which to add Bluetooth functionality to Java applications.
- [Avetana Blootooth](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml) - JSR-82 implementation provides Bluetooth functionalities to Java software in a standardized way.